# Display update button for SiteTreeURLSegmentField if Title has changed - SilverStripe 3.4.0

Tags: silverstripe

I've got two fields on my DataObject 'Title' and 'URLSegment'.

I'd like to get the same behavior here as on a page. That when the Title field is changed, a small button appears to auto update the URLSegment on click.

I can't find a solution in the Docs / [Api](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-SiteTreeURLSegmentField.html)

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: can you not just copy all the relevant code from `SiteTree` ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the `FormField` `SiteTreeURLSegmentField` is tightly coupled to the `SiteTree` class, which means it can't be used on general `DataObjects`.

You'll have to either look at copying that class and amending it to be more generic or building some other solution yourself.